# Angular 7 children component route without parent route

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with routes in my Angular 7 application. I have a page frame, where I would like to switch to different components according to route without refreshing / changing main page frame.
In my page frame I have `<router-outlet>`.
My main route is `http://localhost:4200/login`.

When I go to this page, I would like to show component which is related to this route.
My second route which I would like to show is `http://localhost:4200/forgot-password`.
I would like to see on exactly the same page second component which is related to forgot password form.
I tried to achieve this with children and it works, but when I make a redirection it adds `/forgot-password` at the end of existing `http://localhost:4200/login` url. In this case I've always receive `http://localhost:4200/login/forgot-password` in url. What I'm trying to achieve is to show in url `http://localhost:4200/forgot-password`, without `/login`.

app.routes.ts

```js
// Login Page
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent,
      canActivate: [ HTTPSGuard ],
      children: [
        {
          path:'',
          component: Login2ComponentComponent,
          data: {
            animation: 'Sign-In'
          }
        },
        {
          path: 'forgot-password',
          component: ForgotPassword2Component,
          data: {
            animation: 'Forgot-Password'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

In my login component I have a link:
`<a [routerLink]="['/forgot-password']">Go to forgot</a>`

But it adds me to the current `/login` route `/forgot-password`.

Maybe there is a router attribute which I can use in `app.routes.ts` to make this happened?

Thank you for help!

Comment: does  `pathMatch: 'full'` change anything? Add it to the first child like this: `{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', ... }`

Comment: Where should I place it?

Comment: Unfortunately, same behaviour as previously.